# expect output only stdout of the command and nothing else

Tags: stdout, expect

How to write expect script which executes command and prints just the command's output?

I've tried various things but none works, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
spawn bash
send "echo 1\r"
log_user 1
expect "1"
log_user 0
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Gives in output:

> echo 1

While I need just "1" . I hope somebody knows simple solution how to fix my example

Comment: how many commands do u want to execute before `exit`?

Comment: let's say I may need to do some prepare work with expect before any output, then execute only one command and show exact output as it was executed in terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capturing the output from sent commands is a bit of a pain in expect.

Here's a more general case that does not rely on the log_user setting, it captures the output with a regular expression:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
spawn bash

# set the prompt to a known value
send "PS1='>'\r"
expect -re {>$}

# send a command: we don't know what the output is going to be
send "echo \$RANDOM\r"

# capture the portion of the output that occurs just before the prompt
expect -re "\r\n(.*?)\r\n>$"
puts "output is: $expect_out(1,string)"

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

---

A thought just occurred to me: if the command does not require any interaction, then expect is overkill: just use `exec`

```
set output [exec bash -c {echo $RANDOM}]
```

Comment: Thank you - that is really good base, I wish I could find something like this earlier. The only missing feature is that it will collect full output and then print all at once; but I guess that just needs additional effort from me. (I need expect for various more complex scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks following script does (at least similar to) what I need:

```
log_user 0
spawn bash
expect "#" {} "\\\$" {}
send -- "echo AA\r"
expect -- "echo AA\r" {}
log_user 1
expect -- "AA"
log_user 0
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```